# Geneating Learning Curve for Logistic Regression

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, scikit-learn

I have a dataset of 260 microscopic image.I want to generate a learning curve for logistic regression algorithm.But I am getting this error "'module' object is not iterable" .Perhaps I don't understand something basic, as I'm a begineer who freshly learning Python

```
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
from imutils import paths
from scipy import misc
import numpy as np
import argparse
import imutils
import cv2
import os
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from sklearn.model_selection import learning_curve
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.metrics import recall_score
from sklearn.metrics import precision_score
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score





def plot_learning_curve(estimator, title, X, y, ylim=None, cv=None,
                        n_jobs=None, train_sizes=np.linspace(50, 80, 110)):
    """
    Generate a simple plot of the test and training learning curve.

    Parameters
    ----------
    estimator : object type that implements the "fit" and "predict" methods
        An object of that type which is cloned for each validation.

    title : string
        Title for the chart.

    X : array-like, shape (n_samples, n_features)
        Training vector, where n_samples is the number of samples and
        n_features is the number of features.

    y : array-like, shape (n_samples) or (n_samples, n_features), optional
        Target relative to X for classification or regression;
        None for unsupervised learning.


    cv : int, cross-validation generator or an iterable, optional
        Determines the cross-validation splitting strategy.
        Possible inputs for cv are:
          - None, to use the default 3-fold cross-validation,
          - integer, to specify the number of folds.
          - :term:`CV splitter`,
          - An iterable yielding (train, test) splits as arrays of indices.

        For integer/None inputs, if ``y`` is binary or multiclass,
        :class:`StratifiedKFold` used. If the estimator is not a classifier
        or if ``y`` is neither binary nor multiclass, :class:`KFold` is used.

        Refer :ref:`User Guide <cross_validation>` for the various
        cross-validators that can be used here.

    n_jobs : int or None, optional (default=None)
        Number of jobs to run in parallel.
        ``None`` means 1 unless in a :obj:`joblib.parallel_backend` context.
        ``-1`` means using all processors. See :term:`Glossary <n_jobs>`
        for more details.

    train_sizes : array-like, shape (n_ticks,), dtype float or int
        Relative or absolute numbers of training examples that will be used to
        generate the learning curve. If the dtype is float, it is regarded as a
        fraction of the maximum size of the training set (that is determined
        by the selected validation method), i.e. it has to be within (0, 1].
        Otherwise it is interpreted as absolute sizes of the training sets.
        Note that for classification the number of samples usually have to
        be big enough to contain at least one sample from each class.
        (default: np.linspace(0.1, 1.0, 5))
    """
    plt.figure()
    plt.title(title)
    if ylim is not None:
        plt.ylim(*ylim)
    plt.xlabel("Training examples")
    plt.ylabel("Score")
    train_sizes, train_scores, test_scores = learning_curve(
        estimator, X, y, cv=cv, n_jobs=n_jobs, train_sizes=train_sizes)
    train_scores_mean = np.mean(train_scores, axis=1)
    train_scores_std = np.std(train_scores, axis=1)
    test_scores_mean = np.mean(test_scores, axis=1)
    test_scores_std = np.std(test_scores, axis=1)
    plt.grid()

    plt.fill_between(train_sizes, train_scores_mean - train_scores_std,
                     train_scores_mean + train_scores_std, alpha=0.1,
                     color="r")
    plt.fill_between(train_sizes, test_scores_mean - test_scores_std,
                     test_scores_mean + test_scores_std, alpha=0.1, color="g")
    plt.plot(train_sizes, train_scores_mean, 'o-', color="r",
             label="Training score")
    plt.plot(train_sizes, test_scores_mean, 'o-', color="g",
             label="Cross-validation score")

    plt.legend(loc="best")
    return plt






#training  with logistic regression
clfLR = LogisticRegression(random_state=0, solver='lbfgs')
clfLR.fit(trainFeat,trainLabels)
acc = clfLR.score(testFeat, testLabels)
print("accuracy of Logistic regression ",acc)
```

I am facing this problem only when i Want to plot the curve.Rest of the code works fine.

```
#plotting the curve
estimator =LogisticRegression()
train_sizes, train_scores, valid_scores = plot_learning_curve(
estimator,'logistic learning curve ', trainFeat, trainLabels, cv=5, n_jobs=4,train_sizes=[50, 80, 110])
print(train_sizes)
plt.show()
```

Screenshot of the error

[learning curve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Auxkq.png)

Comment: Show the complete stack trace of error.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the code on Jupyter online IDE IDE. It plots automatically if you add "%matplotlib" line to import section.

If you want to keep working on this IDE, share your error message so maybe I can help you. You are missing one of the imports probably or it might be a Python2/3 problem.